# Сортировка чисел си

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка

Я нашел средние значения каждого столбца матрицы. Теперь эти средние значения надо отсортировать по возрастанию. Как это сделать?

```
for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
{ 
    int srznach = 0;
    for (r = 0; r < m; r++)
    {
        srznach = srznach + a[r][c];
    }
    printf("  %d", (srznach / m));
}
```

Comment: Объявите массив, имеющий число элементов равного числу столбцов в исходной матрице, запишите туда средние значения и отсортируйте их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так устроит?

```
int cmp(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
    double d1 = *(double*)p1;
    double d2 = *(double*)p2;
    return
        (d1 > d2) ?  1 :
        (d1 < d2) ? -1 : 0;
}

int main()
{
    #define  n 6
    #define  m 4
    int r, c;

    int a[m][n];

    for(r = 0; r < m; ++r)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < n; ++c)
        {
            a[r][c] = rand()%100;
            printf("%4d",a[r][c]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");


    double avg[n];

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        double srznach = 0.0;
        for (r = 0; r < m; r++)
        {
            srznach = srznach + a[r][c];
        }
        avg[c] = srznach/m;
    }

    qsort(avg,n,sizeof(double),cmp);

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        printf("%lf\n",avg[c]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Можете объяснить как происходила сортировка?

Comment: Стандартная библиотечная функция `qsort` - см. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort

Comment: спасибо за помощь закрываем